# CorePlot inside detail view of Split View

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, core-plot

I'm attempting to load a CPXYGraph into the detail view of a split view controller. I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when it attempts to display the plot data.

I create a new project based on "Split View-based application". After adding the CorePlot framework I make the following modifications:

1- add a GraphController (.m, .h and .xib). The xib contains a UIView with a subordinate view of type CPLayerHostingView. 
2- add the following line to the app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
 [detailViewController performSelector:@selector(configureView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

3- add the following to DetailViewController configureView

```
 CGRect graphFrame = CGRectMake(0, 43, 662, 450);
 GraphController *graphController = [[[GraphController alloc]
   initWithNibName:@"GraphController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
 [graphController.view setFrame:graphFrame];
 [self.view addSubview:graphController.view];
 [graphController reloadData];
```

4- the reloadData method in GraphController is pretty much pasted from one of the CorePlot samples (DatePlot) and I will copy and paste (most of) it here-

```
-(void)reloadData
{
    if (!graph)
    {
        [self parentViewController];
        [self.view addSubview:layerHost];

        // Create graph from theme
        graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        CPTheme *theme = [CPTheme themeNamed:@"Dark Gradients"];
        [graph applyTheme:theme];
        ....
        [layerHost setHostedLayer: graph];
        ....
        // Setup scatter plot space
        CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
        NSTimeInterval xLow = 0.0f;
        plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(xLow) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(oneDay*5.0f)];
        plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(1.0) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(3.0)];

        // Axes
        CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
        CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
        x.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromFloat(oneDay);
        x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromString(@"2");
        x.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle;
        CPTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[CPTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter] autorelease];
        timeFormatter.referenceDate = refDate;
        x.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;

        CPXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
        y.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromString(@"0.5");
        y.minorTicksPerInterval = 5;
        y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromFloat(oneDay);

        // Create a plot that uses the data source method
        CPScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[[CPScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
        dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"Date Plot";
        dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 3.f;
        dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor greenColor];
        dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
        **[graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];**

        // Add some data
        NSMutableArray *newData = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSUInteger i;
        for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            NSTimeInterval x = oneDay*i;
            id y = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:1.2*rand()/(float)RAND_MAX + 1.2];
            [newData addObject:
             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
              [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:x], [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPScatterPlotFieldX], 
              y, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPScatterPlotFieldY], 
              nil]];
        }
        plotData = newData;
    }
}
```

The offending line is [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot]; If I comment this out the simulator comes up and displays the x and y axis of the graph and of course no data. Adding this line back causes the following SIGART-

```
2010-09-15 14:35:58.959 SplitViewWithCorePlot[17301:207] relabel <<CPScatterPlot: 0x4c458c0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {558, 386}}>
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're retaining the data array anywhere. Try changing the last statement to

```
plotData = [newData retain];
```

or, if you have a property defined for it,

```
self.plotData = newData;
```

Eric

Comment: I'm running the same (CP) code in a project without a Split View and it works. I'd definitely like to have the Split View as an option though.